# Error creating SQL Model Connection connection to Oracle 11g database

Tags: eclipse, oracle, jpa, oracle11gr2, database-connectivity

I am trying to generate entity classes from oracle 11g database tables using JPA project in STS 4 IDE

I am setting following properties for database connection

> jdbcurl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:dummy"
>
> user= dummy
>
> password = dummy
>
> database = dummy

I have even set **sec_case_sensitive_logon=false** in Oracle 11g database

[properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M10iW.png)

[ping success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIRPe.png)

during entity generation in JPA tool, I am getting following error

[Error creating SQL model connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86Nfg.png)

Comment: What are the details of the failures? Why *should* it work--you haven't shown us that these are the right credentials.

Comment: What is the error i cant see images

Comment: i have uploaded error creating SQL "model connection" dialog box screenshot
i dont have enough credits to make it visible in question post, just click on the  
 < model connection failed > link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to connect with "generic jdbc" connection profile in which some properties were missing (**database instance**= *servicename/sid*,**catalog**=*all/dba/user*) which were available in Oracle connection profile got from DTP installed from plugin manager as follows:

> Help -> install new software -> work with (spring tool suite 4) ->
> check following options
>
> -database development
> -data tools platform connectivity
> -data tools platform enablement
> -data tools platform enablement for oracle

and then followed the steps from following blogs :

> Step 1 : [add connection profile](http://shengwangi.blogspot.com/2014/12/how-to-add-oracle-db-connection-in-eclipse.html)
>
> Step 2 : [create java classes from existing database table](http://shengwangi.blogspot.com/2014/12/how-to-create-java-classes-from-tables.html)